# Spinner triggering at the wrong time

Tags: android, spinner

I've been stuck on an android Spinner for few hours and I can't find out what's wrong in my way to do.

I've set the onItemSelectedListener method but it triggers when my activity launch, and the fact to click on an item in the list doesn't change anything. Here is the code :

Custom adapter of Spinner:

```
public class spinnerUrgenceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

ArrayList<UrgenceSpin> list;
    Context ctx;

    public spinnerUrgenceAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<UrgenceSpin> list) {
        super(context, 0, list);
        this.list = list;
        this.ctx=context;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return customView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        return customView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    public View customView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        UrgenceSpin us = (UrgenceSpin) getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, parent, false);
        }

        Button cercle = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.urgenceDSpin);
        TextView nom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.urgenceLSpin);

        cercle.setBackground(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(us.getIdDrawable()));
        nom.setText(us.getNomUrgence());

        return convertView;
    }
```

The way I create it and implements the listener :

```
final int[] urgencesDr = {R.drawable.no_urgence, R.drawable.faible_urgence, R.drawable.moyenne_urgence, R.drawable.pressant_urgence, R.drawable.urgent_urgence};
        final String[] urgencesLa = {"Pas d'urgence", "Urgence très faible" , "Peu urgent", "Pressant", "Urgent"};

        ArrayList<UrgenceSpin> urgsp = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            urgsp.add(new UrgenceSpin(urgencesDr[i], urgencesLa[i]));
        }

        Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.urgencespin);
        spinnerUrgenceAdapter sua = new spinnerUrgenceAdapter(CreationSav.this, urgsp);
        spin.setAdapter(sua);


        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Button urgenceD = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.urgenceDSpin);
                TextView urgenceL = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.urgenceLSpin);
                Toast.makeText(CreationSav.this, " yolo "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                /*
                UrgenceSpin current = new UrgenceSpin(urgencesDr[position], urgencesLa[position]);
                urgenceD.setBackground(CreationSav.this.getResources().getDrawable(current.getIdDrawable()));
                urgenceL.setText(current.getNomUrgence());
                */
                }          


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

As you can notice, my final goal is to change the button and the textView (screenshot at the end)
and the XML for the adapter :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="13dp"
        android:layout_height="13dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/urgenceDSpin"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:id="@+id/urgenceLSpin"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So as you can notice on screenshot the Row appears when I click on my spinner, but clicking one of these items doesn't do anything. And when my activity launches, I got my toast that says : Yolo 0

[image]

What is wrong with the way I did, and could you explain me if I'm doing it right? I just tried to follow the basis but it just doesn't work... And also, is that possible to do what I'm trying to do (replace the current element in the spinner by the selected element)

Comment: As 0th item by default selected, may causing you onItemSelected() triggered. you can try with setOnItemClickListener.

Comment: this method doesn't work with spinners and causes an exception

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    int  selectionCurrent = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if (selectionCurrent != i) {
       }
       selectionCurrent = i;


    }
```